# Sonarqube css scan issue

Tags: css, sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan

I have sonaqube server and seperate teamcity server, I have added a step in teamcity configuration to run sonar runner on my css code repository (in bitbucket).

Sonarqube server - Sonarqube 6.7

pluins added - sonarqube-6.7\extensions\plugins\sonar-css-plugin-4.13

I am facing issue related to sonarqube scanning on .css files:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyze file: E:/LocalAgent2/work/fe98ca8c22f54520/SourceCode/UI Design/Source/src/css/components.css
...
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyze file: E:/LocalAgent2/work/fe98ca8c22f54520/SourceCode/UI       Design/Source/src/css/components.css
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 17 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File css/components.css has 16 character(s) at line 351
```

I have updated format of .css file from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM, then this issue goes off but parsing error issue comes up. It is not able to parse then, please help.

```
ERROR - Unable to parse file: E:/LocalAgent4/work/fe98ca8c22f54520/SourceCode/UI Design/Source/src/css/components.css ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 2:
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 17 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File css/components.css has 16 character(s) at line 351
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS? specifically line 351.

Comment: Resloved:Actual issue was UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
Resloved: Actual issue was UTF-8 encoding. I tried to run scanner on actual code via cmd prompt with all required parameters available inside "sonar-project.properties" file. 

sonar.projectKey=simple-css-scss-less-project
sonar.projectName=Simple CSS / SCSS / Less Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

And it was working fine, i am able to see scanned output inside sonar dashboard.

Then I have updated TeamCity configuration. Added build step with Sonar Runner and provided below mentioned parameters.
Project name:
Project key:
Project version:%build.number%
Most important part which resolved my issue --> Additional parameter section i have to add below line.

-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```